# How to reference the far right worksheet in another workbook, for a VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, vlookup, worksheet

I am writing a vlookup function and I want to reference the last tab in a another workbook, rather than the tab name as it changes daily.

To move to the last tab in the workbook I have

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
```

Is it possible to reference this in the a VLOOKUP? (left a blank where the worksheet should be)

```
 "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]"     "'!C4:C7,4,0)"
```

Comment: Did you tried @braX answer? what problem\error did you encountered after trying it?

Comment: Hi - Yes tried both but not getting much result. I get a 424 Object required error.

Comment: Could you share the line in which you tried, cause that should have given you the formula. Are you using this procedure to write the formula, or you are using it as a function in a worksheet?

Comment: im quite new to VBA, but whatever i am copying into the macro is not working correctly. I originally wrote the function, and tried copying what was listed below. Which one listed should work?

Comment: Could you include the entire function in your post, so we can have a better idea of what your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: just commented a reply below - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head (untested), but maybe something like this

```
Dim wbData as Workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Add("Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],[" & wbData.Name & "]" & wbData.WorkSheets(wbData.WorkSheets.Count).Name & "!C4:C7,4,0)"
wbData.Close False
```

Alternatively, using the `.Open` method:

```
Dim wbData as Workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],[" & wbData.Name & "]" & wbData.WorkSheets(wbData.WorkSheets.Count).Name & "!C4:C7,4,0)"
wbData.Close False
```

*Adjust Sheet1 and A1 to your needs*

But still, you would need to trigger this code on an event of some sort, which isn't clear to me yet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the .name part? I cant use the name of the worksheet as it changes daily

I am getting a 1004 error with that formula above

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit more on when you are setting this formula? Have you tried maybe the `Workbook_NewSheet` event? You could have it change the formula when there is a new worksheet added that way...

Comment: Thanks - I am quite new to VBA and only really started using it a couple of weeks back. Seems I am just stuck on this part mainly. Unsure how to add the above code in to reference a newly added worksheet in the Lookup

Comment: I updated it with something else to try. But as I said, you need to know *when* to run this code...

Comment: Thanks. Still not got it to work, i might have to think of an alternative such as copying the data onto a new workbook and VLookup off that with just 1 worksheet named Sheet1, rather than trying to reference the latest created tab on the first workbook :-(

Comment: Or maybe someone else will have an idea for you... Other people may answer later..

Comment: I have tried both formulas and getting a 1004 error. Its not letting me past the formula on both

Answer (score 0):

The Function I am at is below;

Currently i am changing the date of the worksheet which the vlookup is referencing. So the below shows "Dec 9" from yesterday. Once the new tab gets created today in the file "Unavista UTI Lookup December2019" - It will show "Dec 10"

```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]Dec 9'!C4:C7,4,0)"
```

What I am trying to do is find a way for the code to automatically change this to todays date. Speaking with someone at work we tried the below

```
Dim DayValue As String
Dim FormulaString As String
DayValue = Format(Date, "mmm d")

 Range("E2").Select
 FormulaString = "=VLOOKUP(EH2,'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]" & DayValue & "' !$D:$G,4,0)"
```

The formula isn't bringing back any error, but unfortunately the lookup isn't doing anything, and just bringing back empty cells.

If anyone can resolve this, as i've tried numerous things and still not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your were applying the formula with a line like this:

```
Range("E2").Formula = FormulaString
```

however when I tried that line, it returned an error as your line has one blank space in excess, as the syntax for a link with another workbook should be:

`'[WorkbookName]WorksheetName'!Range`

and your line has:

`'[WorkbookName]WorksheetName' !Range`

Therefore instead of this:

`FormulaString = "=VLOOKUP(EH2,'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]" & DayValue & "' !$D:$G,4,0)"`

use this:

`FormulaString = "=VLOOKUP(EH2,'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]" & DayValue & "'!$D:$G,4,0)"`
`Range("E2").Formula = FormulaString`

However, in order to ease the maintenance of the procedure I suggest to use a constant, try this procedure:

```
Sub Formula_Today()
Const kFml As String = "= VLOOKUP( RC[133]," & _
    "'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]#TODAY'!C4:C7, 4, 0 )"
Dim sFml As String
    sFml = Replace(kFml, "#TODAY", Format(Date, "mmm d"))
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
        .Range("E2:E10").FormulaR1C1 = sFml
    End With
    End Sub
```

***Before adding the new worksheet***
[image]

***After adding the new worksheet and applying the `Formula_Today` procedure***
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately i'm still not able to get it to work with your formula. Unless I am adding it incorrectly into the Module, i'm getting an error still. With my formula i have no error, the macro works, but the formula isnt picking up the value to the workbook i am referencing. The formula works perfectly wiht the below, the issue is, its not updating the tab name each day - 

   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]Dec 10'!C4:C7,4,0)"

Comment: What is the formula entered by my procedure?

Comment: i am thinking i might have entered it incorrectly, is there a correct way to include with within all my code?

Comment: Just show us how are you using the function? What code are you using to automatically update everyday. Then we'll have something to work with.